# Creating a Checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, widget

I'm trying to create a checkbox option for one of my widgets in *Wordpress*, so that when it is checked it will display/reveal some content.

The problem is that it won't reveal the content when the checkbox is checked.

```
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="tcheckbox" class="checkbox" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('checkbox'); ?>" value="1" <?php checked( '1', $checkbox ); ?>/>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('checkbox');?>"><?php _e('My Checkbox.'); ?></label>

        <div id="tcheckboxdiv" style="display:none">
            <p>T One:</p>
            <p><input type="text" class="widefat" name="one" placeholder="1" readonly></p>
            <p>T Two:</p>
            <p><input type="text" class="widefat" name="two" placeholder="2" readonly></p>
        </div>
    </p>            

    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery("#tcheckbox").change(function() {
            jQuery("#tcheckboxdiv").fadeToggle("slow");
        });
    });
    </script>
```

As I'm fairly new to javaScript and PHP, I was wondering if there is any conflicting scripts above, as it seems to work perfectly fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/GhZDP/

Thank you.

Comment: What does your parsed output look like?

Comment: Multi-post: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/92398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the jsFiddle is working perfectly fine, the script above wont work as it is not being output correctly in the source of *Wordpress*.

The *Wordpress* admin pages also use javaScript and this causes a clash in the coding.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is rather hard to reproduce since it is actually working in the Fiddle you provided.

What I would do in your situation is check if the code gets executed by just throwing in an `alert()` within the `jQuery(window).load()`

After that, try different approaches to listen for `DOM ready`:

```
jQuery(function () {
    // Code here
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // Code here
});
```

This is not really an answer to your solution but rather support to help you debug this problem. It was too big (and became unreadable) to post in a comment though.

You could also try a delegated event listener like this (this requires you to add the 'widgetForm' ID to your `<form>` tag):

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#widgetForm").on("change", "#logocheckbox", function () {
        // Your code goes here; e.g. $("#logocheckboxdiv").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

But again, I'm just guessing and helping you debug since I can't really reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Robin.  Yes, it is rather odd that it seems to be working in the jsFiddle but not in _Wordpress_.  javaScript/jQuery and PHP aren't my strong points so I'm having a little difficulty implementing your solution (creating an `alert()` and listening for `DOM ready`).  If it's not too much to ask, could you possibly drop **[this](http://pastebin.com/H1tCJKg0)** script into your `functions.php` file of any theme on your end to reproduce the problem?  I would really appreciate it and thank you for all your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery object `$` won't work on WordPress since WP operates in noConflict mode. You should call jQuery as `jQuery`, not as `$`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(window).load(function() {
    jQuery('#logocheckbox').change(function() {
        jQuery("#logocheckboxdiv").fadeToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Also, [please don't post duplicate questions](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/92398/creating-a-checkbox)!